Can't authenticate git with chromium.googlesource.com
I was following the setup instructions in https://skia.org/docs/user/download/ when I realized that I needed to authenticate with the repositories at https://chromium.googlesource.com. The problem is that when I navigated to chromium.googlesource.com/new-password in order to generate a password, I followed the setup instructions by pasting the script it gives into my terminal session. Then I reran the clone, but I got the error
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
Cloning into 'depot_tools'...
remote: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage]
remote: locale: "en-US"
remote: message: "Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier: https://chromium.googlesource.com/new-password"
remote:
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "f6caddf116ae43f0902e33b7d103fb04"
fatal: unable to access 'https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400

Generic permissions error. I've tried multiple times to make sure I didn't do anything stupid, including revoking and regenerating the cookie, manually pasting it into my ~/.gitcookies instead of using the script, putting it in my ~/.netrc.
I'm not behind a proxy. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Is any other new user experiencing this issue?

After a ton of debugging and trying it on a different machine, I realized that I had a Bearer Auth Token set as an http.extraheader in my git configuration. How it got there, I have no idea, but as soon as I commented it out I was able to clone successfully. Seems that google's api is more strict about that sort of stuff than github.
